# Error when loading a BERT model using load_model after adding a new token to the tokenizer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am getting this error when trying to load the saved .h5 model in tensorflow:

```
load_model("path_to_model.h5", custom_objects={"TFBertModel": TFBertModel, "AdamWeightDecay": AdamWeightDecay})

ValueError: Cannot assign value to variable 
' tf_bert_model/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight:0': Shape mismatch.The variable shape (30523, 768), and the assigned value shape (2, 768) are incompatible.`
```

Steps to reproduce the error:

- load the pretrained *bert-base-uncased* model and tokenizer from the transformers library
- add a new token to the tokenizer and resize token embeddings
- finetune the model
- save the model
- load the model

Everything works fine if I don't add new tokens. The problem arises only when I add a new token:

```
tokenizer.add_tokens(['new_token'])
bert.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))
```